# Is it possible to re-run componentDidMount when executing a function?

Tags: reactjs

At the moment my componentDidMount retrieves jobs from the database and displays them on my main page.

I created a function called deleteJob, which deletes a Job. The problem is that I have to refresh the page to see the changes.

Is it possible to see the change immediately **without refreshing the page?** I thought this could be done if I somehow made componentDidMount run again when executing the function

Please let me know if this is possible.

```
  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get("/getJobs").then(result => {
        console.log("appear!");
      this.setState({ jobData: result.data }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
  });
    });
    axios.get("/getServices").then(result => {
      this.setState({ serviceData: result.data }, () => {
      });
  });

deleteJob() {
    axios.get("/deleteJob/" + this.props.id).then(result => {
      });
    this.props.close()
}
```

Comment: Can you not run `axios.get("/getJobs")` inside the `then` of `deleteJob` and update the state?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you see the change? Because it updates the state.

So you should update your state when you delete a job.

Better, extract the axios "getJobs" to a method of the class and then call it in componentDidMount, and in deleteJobs.

This way, you will refresh your state at each action.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is fetch the jobs again after deleting the job, also you can separate your functions by their behavior so you can call them in different cases

```js
componentDidMount() {
  getJobs();
  getServices();
}

getJobs() {
  axios.get("/getJobs" + this.props.id).then(result => {
       this.setState({ jobData: result.data }
  });
}

getServices() {
  axios.get("/getServices").then(result => {
      this.setState({ serviceData: result.data }
  });
}


deleteJob() {
  axios.get("/deleteJob/" + this.props.id).then(result => {
     getJobs(); // get jobs again after deletion
  });
  this.props.close()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just filter the state with the id which you are deleting

lets say

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("/getJobs").then(result => {
      this.setState({ jobData: result.data }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
  });
}
```

you can call a delete method on Click of a button

```
   //Assuming the delete request is post Id
    deleteJob =(id)=>{
    deleteJob() {
      axios.post("/deleteJob/" ,+ id)

      //this will filter out the deleted job from existing state
      let filteredJobs = this.state.jobData.filter(data=>data.id===id)

       this.setState({
            jobData:filteredJobs
       )}
}
```

This will re-render the component without refreshing page and no API calls :)